# Unable to instantiate Chrome browser using Protractor

Tags: protractor

Protractor execution if failed due to an exception leaving behind orphan chrome browsers.
To handle this issue, I have create a batch file to kill chrome.exe using taskkill @ batch file. Once I triggered this batch file, protractor test cases which used to work stopped working with below stack trace. Restarted the machine but in vain.

Comment: 17:39:02.300 Using the selenium server at http://localhost:4444/wd/hub
17:39:02.300 [launcher] Running 1 instances of WebDriver
17:40:05.193 
17:40:05.193 C:\Users\vagrant\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\error.js:26
17:40:05.193 [launcher] Process exited with error code 1
17:40:05.193   constructor(opt_error) {
17:40:05.193                          ^
17:40:05.193 WebDriverError: unknown error: unable to discover open pages
17:40:05.193   (Driver info: chromedriver=2.21.371459 ,platform=Windows

Comment: Edited question to add the stack trace, above comment can be deleted now